# Pass pointer to private member function from another class

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I want to create some callback function to a class. The callback should be not static to have access to the private member variables.
For better understanding I made a short example for developing this feature. The problem I have is that the function pointer works for a *no class function* but not for a *private member function*.

The function pointer address itself is correct, I verified using `printf("%p", cb)`

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

typedef void f_t (int);

class First {
    public:
        First(void(cb)(int type)) { mFunc = cb; }
        void start(int type) { (mFunc)(type); }

    private:
        f_t* mFunc;
};

class Second {
    public:
        Second() {};

        void start() {
            //First *my = new First((void(*)(int))&Second::onEvt);
            First *my = new First(reinterpret_cast<f_t*>(&Second::onEvt));
            my->start(123);
        }

    private:
        void onEvt(int type) {
            printf("onEvt type: %d\n", type);
        }

};


void onEvt2(int type) {
    printf("onEvt2 type: %d\n", type);
}

int main() {
    First *my = new First((void(*)(int))&onEvt2);
    my->start(456);

    Second *sec = new Second();
    sec->start();

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
onEvt2 type: 456                                                                                                 
onEvt type: 0
```

I tried different ways of casting but nothing worked for me. I'm not sure if I'm casting on the correct class maybe I have to cast on `First` class

Is it possible at all to have such a feature?

This feature should be nearly the same as you can find as `wxCommandEventHandler` in the `wxWidgets` library.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT - SOLVED**

The first answer in the linked dupplicate was the solution. Here is my working example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders; // for `_1`


class First {
    public:
        First(std::function<void(int)> cb) { mFunc = cb; }
        void start(int type) { (mFunc)(type); }

    private:
        std::function<void(int)> mFunc;
};

class Second {
    public:
        Second() {};

        void start() {
            First *my = new First(std::bind(&Second::onEvt, this, _1));
            my->start(123);
            my->start(456);
        }

    private:
        void onEvt(int type) {
            printf("onEvt type: %d\n", type);
        }

};

void onEvt2(int type) {
    printf("onEvt2 type: %d\n", type);
}

int main() {
    First *my = new First(onEvt2);
    my->start(789);

    Second *sec = new Second();
    sec->start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Useful rule of thumb: never cast a function. If your function is the wrong type, using it is undefined.

Comment: `std::function`  is your friend.

Comment: @molbdnilo when trying to pick one function from an overload set, casting can be useful iirc

Comment: @user463035818 The point of rules of thumb is that there are situations when they don't apply, but they almost always do.